# Any way to have color of font be value in css?

Tags: css, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

Using Visual Studio 2013 and 2015. When viewing the css is there anyway to have the font's color be the actual value? So if, in the css we had....

```
.label-danger, .badge-danger {
  background-color: #ED5565;
  color: #FFFFFF; }
```

..... then the "#ED5565" portion would actually have the font color of "#ED5565"? The only wierd issue would be if the font was too light, like white, I guess.

My objective is to quickly see the actual color. Even if it's a BOX next to it or something.

Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want to happen?
[image.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eERya.jpg)

If so, you need to add Visual Studio tool for color highlighter